# Prestashop - Is there any way to call a function when updating stock quantity?

Tags: php, prestashop

I would like to know is there any simple way to call a function, fe. sending POST request to the external API when updating stock quantity? Including all of the possibilities, like buying, updating from admin dashboard etc. ?

The prestashop version I am currently using is 1.7.7.6 , so the newest.

Comment: You can find some examples here
https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/webservice/tutorials/prestashop-webservice-lib/retrieve-resource/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using javascript event `updateProduct`

```
prestashop.on('updatedProduct', foo);
function foo(){
//Code here
}
```

[Documentation](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/themes/reference/javascript-events/)

Answer (score 0):

Hook `actionUpdateQuantity` is executed in `StockAvailable` class, whenever any quantity update operation takes place.

You will have to hook some module to it and implement a function:

```php
public function hookActionUpdateQuantity($params)
{
    // your API logic here..
}
```

For `$params` the function will receive product ID, combination ID, quantity being set and shop ID:

```php
Hook::exec(
    'actionUpdateQuantity',
            [
                'id_product' => $id_product,
                'id_product_attribute' => $id_product_attribute,
                'quantity' => $quantity,
                'id_shop' => $id_shop,
            ]
);
```